# Indenting partially selected lines in TextMate

Tags: textmate, indentation

Is there any way to make TextMate indent an entire line when only part of it is selected?  Currently, when I select several lines by dragging my mouse over them, or holding shift and pressing up/down, pressing the indent key (Opt-TAB) only shifts the *selected* portion of the line by one indent level.  That is worse than useless to a programmer, because it ruins your code on that line that's getting split apart.  Every other editor that I've ever used recognizes that you actually want to indent that entire line, and does just that.

I've heard that TextMate is incredibly customizable, so I'm hoping that someone knows a way to make it act like one expects.  Maybe so that pressing the indent key expands the selection to include the whole line automatically, and then does the indent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press Select Line (cmd-shift-L) after mousing. That will make any partial-line selections into full-line selections.

Comment: It's an extra step, which is unfortunate, but it works as advertised.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Text/IndentLine" (Alt-Cmd-[) on partially selected lines does the job on my machine.

Comment: Hmm, that command has an interesting effect on my code, but not what I'm looking for.  It appears to take the selected lines and line them all up with some "intelligent" indent level... but I really don't want _all_ of them ending up at the same level.  I just want to move the entire block over by 1 indent (to preserve additional indentation on long, multi-line statements).